# No terminal in Applications menu

Tags: 10.04, command-line

I have recently bought a dedicated server, which is running Ubuntu 10.4, but there is no terminal in the applications or in system. How do I add it for easy access (I'm new to Linux).

Comment: if it is a server, aren't you lready using comand line¿

Answer (score 1):

In a default Ubuntu 10.04 installation, the terminal can be opened via **Applications ▸ Accessories ▸ Terminal**. If this menu item does not exist, you should consult the company that installed the operating system for you.

Answer (score 0):

Right click Applications -> Edit Menus -> Accessories -> check the box next to Terminal.

You can also add a new item to the menu by again right clicking Applications -> Edit Menus -> Accessories -> New Item. The command for the terminal is `gnome-terminal`